# PostgreSQL: How do I get data from table `A` filtered by a column in table `B`

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to fetch all parents that have kids in a specific grade only in a school.
Below are trimmed down version of the tables.

```
TABLE students
  id,
  last_name,
  grade_id,
  school_id

TABLE parents_students
  parent_id,
  student_id

TABLE parents
  id,
  last_name,
  school_id
```

I tried the below query but it doesn't really work as expected. It rather fetches all parents in a school disregarding the grade. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  p.id,
  p.last_name,
  p.school_id,
  st.school_id,
  st.grade_id, 
FROM parents p
  INNER JOIN students st ON st.school_id = p.school_id
WHERE st.grade_id = 118
AND st.school_id = 6
GROUP BY p.id,st.grade_id,st.school_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think:

```
select p.*
from parents p
where exists (select 1
              from parents_students ps join
                   students s
                   on ps.student_id = s.id
              where ps.parent_id = p.id and
                    s.grade_id = 118 and
                    s.school_id = 6
             );
```

Your question says that you want information about the *parents*.  If so, I don't see why you are including redundant information about the school and grade (it is redundant because the `where` clause specifies exactly what those values are).